# Using tebeka selenium in GUI borwser mode

Tags: selenium, go

I am trying to automate a webpage testing using selenium with golang from [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tebeka/selenium). When I run this [example](https://github.com/tebeka/selenium/blob/master/example_test.go), I don't find the browser window opening. Looks like it is running in headless mode. How do I run it in GUI browser mode?

Comment: I don't see anything that would make firefox run in headless mode. Are you sure that the program is being run at all (since the linked program requires some subtle change to actually run)? What are output of the program? Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, there were some errors - like extra \n in println function. After fixing that, the output is coming as expected.
```  
Hello WebDriver!
Program exited.
```

Comment: Seems like you need to set up an X server, and supply the screen location, and an (optional) Xauthority file path to [`selenium.Display`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tebeka/selenium#Display) function. The example used a virtual frame buffer which won't show itself.